# Gatsby StaticImage from array

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to make an image slider with React and Gatsby but the images aren't rendering and I get this in console

```
static-image.server.tsx:51 No data found for image "undefined"
              Could not find values for the following props at build time: src
```

This is my code. When I change the image source to `'../images/1.png'` instead of `images[sliderIndex]` the image will show.

```
const ImageSlider = (props) => {

  const [sliderIndex, setSliderIndex] = useState(0);
  const images = ['../images/1.png', '../images/2.png']

  useEffect(() => {
    const sliderLoop = setInterval(() => {
      if(sliderIndex+1 > images.length-1) {
        setSliderIndex(0)
      } else {
        setSliderIndex(sliderIndex+1)
      }
    }, 5000)
    return () => clearInterval(sliderLoop)
  }, [sliderIndex])

  console.log(sliderIndex)

  return (
    <>
      {props.children}
      <StaticImage src={images[sliderIndex]} alt=""/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: StaticImage properities, including src must be defined or calculated in the very moment of building application. If you need src to be changed you have to chose GatsbyImage component. But if you make a slider it might be nice idea to have every image as StatisImage and just manage their visibility and/or positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<StaticImage />` would only works with a static string, see [this part of the docs for more info](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage).

You'd have to use the `<GatsbyImage />` component instead & query image data manually, as [instructed here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/using-gatsby-plugin-image/#dynamic-images). I copied the relevant sample code below.

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
function BlogPost({ data }) {
  const image = getImage(data.blogPost.avatar)
  return (
    <section>
      <h2>{data.blogPost.title}</h2>
      <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={data.blogPost.author} />
      <p>{data.blogPost.body}</p>
    </section>
  )
}
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    blogPost(id: { eq: $Id }) {
      title
      body
      author
      avatar {
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(
            width: 200
            placeholder: BLURRED
            formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```